# Cypress Test - Filtering results based on a URL query parameter

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I have the following in Cypress v12.17:

```
it.only('Foo Test', () => {
  cy.intercept('somePath/someEndpoint**', { fixture: 'someJsonFile' }).as('getFoo');

  cy.visit('somePath/someEndpoint?queryParamOne=someValue');

  cy.wait('@getFoo').then((interception) => {
    console.log('URL', JSON.stringify(interception.request.url));
    console.log('QUERY', JSON.stringify(interception.request.query));
  });
});
```

When executing the test, the left pane (where it shows pass/fail) shows the full url of `https://someHost/somePath/someEndpoint?queryParamOne=someValue`

However, the `interception.request.url` only shows `https://someHost/somePath/someEndpoint` and `interception.request.query` shows `{}`

How do I access `queryParamOne=someValue` from inside the interception?  I need the key and value to filter the contents of `interception.response.body` before returning the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't really pinpoint where your code is going wrong, but I can make it work with the following changes:

- using regex for the intercept (because life's too short for messing with glob)
- dropping the `JSON.stringify()` in the interception because it's easier to test an object than a string

```js
cy.intercept(/somePath\/someEndpoint/, { fixture: 'example.json' })
  .as('my-intercept')

// Fire the network request
cy.window().then(win => win.fetch('somePath/someEndpoint?queryParamOne=someValue'))

cy.wait('@my-intercept')
  .then((interception) => {
    console.log('QUERY', interception.request.query)
    return interception.request.query
  })
  .should('have.property', 'queryParamOne', 'someValue')
```

[image]

---

#### Specifying the query in the RouteMatcher

Since there's no substantial difference between your code and mine, I am guessing there is another call without query parameters that is consuming your intercept (or rather the `cy.wait()`).

If that's the case, you can make the intercept more specific by specifying the query in the RouteMatcher.

In this example I've added a prior call to `'somePath/someEndpoint'` that I want to ignore (since it has no query parameter).

I've used a wildcard for the parameter value using regex `/.+/` which means the query value has at least one character.

```js
cy.intercept({
    path: /somePath\/someEndpoint/, 
    query: {queryParamOne: /.+/},   
  },
  { fixture: 'example.json' }
).as('my-intercept')

// Fire the network requests
cy.window().then(win => win.fetch('somePath/someEndpoint'))
cy.window().then(win => win.fetch('somePath/someEndpoint?queryParamOne=someValue'))

cy.wait('@my-intercept')
  .then((interception) => {
    console.log('QUERY', interception.request.query)
    return interception.request.query
  })
  .should('have.property', 'queryParamOne', 'someValue')
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the great answer and explanation!